# Catching wrong array reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, reference, manpage

How do I catch wrong array reference in C++? Why doesn't the following code work:

```
    #include <exception>

    int * problemNum = new int;
    int (* p [100])() = {problem1, problem2, problem3};

    ...

    try {
        cout << (*p[*problemNum-1])();
    }
    catch (exception){
        cout << "No such problem";
    }
```

My compiler says: *Unhandled exception at 0xcccccccc in Euler.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.* when I initiate bad reference by inputting `0` as *problemNum.

Answer (score 4):

alamar is right - C++ won't catch exceptions with this type of array.

Use an STL vector instead:

```
#include <exception>
#include <vector>

int * problemNum = new int;
std::vector<int(*)()> p;
p.push_back(problem1);
p.push_back(problem2);
p.push_back(problem3);

...

try {
    cout << p.at(*problemNum-1)();
}
catch (exception){
    cout << "No such problem";
}
```

Comment: That won't trigger an exception, either. If you need an exception when accessing an out-of-bounds element, use the "at" member function, not the bracket operator.

Comment: Dang you're right Rob, I never knew that! I'll change the code example.

Answer (score 3):

Becauce C++ can't handle such errors with its exception mechanism.
See [Defective C++](http://www.yosefk.com/c++fqa/defective.html#defect-4) on that issue.

Use `sigaction(2)`.

*sigaction - examine and change a signal action*

SYNOPSIS

```
   #include <signal.h>

   int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,
                 struct sigaction *oldact);
```

DESCRIPTION
       The  sigaction()  system call is used to change the action taken by a process on receipt of a specific
       signal.
       signum specifies the signal and can be any valid signal except SIGKILL and SIGSTOP.
       If act is non-null, the new action for signal signum is installed from act.  If  oldact  is  non-null,
       the previous action is saved in oldact.
       The sigaction structure is defined as something like:

```
       struct sigaction {
           void     (*sa_handler)(int);
           void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
           sigset_t   sa_mask;
           int        sa_flags;
           void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
       };
```

You need to catch SIGSEGV, you can attach your own handler (function which gets called when illegal memory access is performed).

Comment: You really don't want to start catching SIGSEGV in this case. It's absolutely wrong to use segmentation faults as an array boundary check. Better just use std::vector.